# How to get the reverse order in BubbleSort Algorithm

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I was studying this code which is using BubbleSort to get the reverse order(high to low) or the random 20 data that have been inserted in the program.
The result should be `result (high to low) : 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`.

However, what I get is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`.

I know that if I change `if (data[j] < data[j - 1])` to `if (data[j] > data[j - 1])`, I can get the right answers.

**However, I wish to ask if there is any other way to change the following code to make this give me the reverse order**

```
temp        = data[j];
data[j]     = data[j - 1];
data[j - 1] = temp;
```

The whole code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COUNT 20
 
int main()
{
    int data[COUNT]
        = { 5 , 15 , 7 , 20 , 1 ,
            4 , 10 , 2 , 8  , 11,
            9 ,  6 , 13, 18 ,  3,
            16, 12 , 14, 17 , 19 };
 
    int temp = 0;
    
    printf("random data : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }
 
 
    //BubbleSort
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = COUNT - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (data[j] < data[j - 1])
            {
                temp        = data[j];
                data[j]     = data[j - 1];
                data[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
 
    //print
    printf("\n\nresult (high to low) : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }
 
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Not really. The basis of any sorting algorithm is the result of the comparison between two  elements of the array. Changing that comparison from a `<` to a `>` is the only real way to change the ordering of the product.

Comment: Yes. One of that is reversing the array after sorting. This can be achieved by changing the specified part to `... temp; }}} /* code to reverse the array here */ {{{`

Comment: Note that the C standard `qsort()` takes a function pointer for the comparison and calls that to compare the elements.  It can be used to encapsulate exotic sort orders, such as “odd values descenfing before even values ascending”.  It also allows you to use a single sort function for different orderings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is inverting the condition. This can be archieved by changing the specified part

```
temp        = data[j];
data[j]     = data[j - 1];
data[j - 1] = temp;
```

to

```
} else {
temp        = data[j];
data[j]     = data[j - 1];
data[j - 1] = temp;
```

Another way is reversing the array after sorting. This can be archieved by changing the specified part

```
temp        = data[j];
data[j]     = data[j - 1];
data[j - 1] = temp;
```

to

```
temp        = data[j];
data[j]     = data[j - 1];
data[j - 1] = temp;
}}}
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT - i - 1; i++) {{{
temp = data[i];
data[i] = data[COUNT - i - 1];
data[COUNT - i - 1] = temp;
```